# Codename One - Extend CheckBox to create a SpanToggleCheckBox

Tags: codenameone

I need toggle buttons that are multi line, because the text of some of them is long. I tried to extend CheckBox to create a SpanToggleCheckBox, but it doesn't work, because no text is shown. What's wrong in the following code? How can I achive my purpose?

```
public class SpanToggleCheckBox extends CheckBox {

    private TextArea textArea;

    /**
     * Constructs a toggle checkbox with the given text
     *
     * @param text to display
     */
    public SpanToggleCheckBox(String text) {
        textArea = new TextArea(getUIManager().localize(text, text));
        textArea.setActAsLabel(true);
        textArea.setColumns(textArea.getText().length() + 1);
        textArea.setUIID("Label");
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        textArea.setFocusable(false);
        this.setUIID("CheckBox");
        super.setToggle(true);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        getUIManager().getLookAndFeel().drawTextArea(g, textArea);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    protected Dimension calcPreferredSize() {
        return getUIManager().getLookAndFeel().getTextAreaSize(textArea, true);
    }

    /**
     * Shorthand for creating the SpanToggleCheckBox
     *
     * @param text the text for the button
     * @return a check box
     */
    public static SpanToggleCheckBox createToggle(String text) {
        SpanToggleCheckBox cb = new SpanToggleCheckBox(text);
        return cb;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue with a different approch.
In the code, I replaced with line of code:

```
Component button = CheckBox.createToggle(label);
```

with these lines:

```
CheckBox myBtn = CheckBox.createToggle("text");
Container container = new Container(BoxLayout.y());
container.setLeadComponent(myBtn);
SpanLabel multiLineText = new SpanLabel(label);
container.add(multiLineText);
```

In this way, I got a Container that acts like a Toggle Button and that contains a SpanLabel with the multiline text.